# Pre-selected Bootstrap radio buttons won't submit

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have an html file containing a form that is being loaded via php. In this form, all input fields show pre-selected values based on previously entered values. When I submit this loaded form, all the textboxes and text inputs are successfully submitted ; however, the radio buttons ( which also have pre-selected values) are not submitted unless, you click on the selected values again. Is there any way I can fix this?

Here's my simplified html that's being loaded:

```
<form action="report" method="POST" target="_blank">
<div class="btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons" id="rop1-1-cons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary active">
         <input type="radio" name="rop1-1-cons" id="rop1-1-cons-5" value="5" autocomplete="off">I
    </label>
</div>
<input type="text" value="Pre-selected User Input"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

The label has "Active" class which means the user have chosen this before the form html was saved.

I think it's useful to mention that I am using bootstrap style radio buttons (I know, they have strange behaviors!)

Comment: Can you upload the html?

Comment: @Unknown Sure. I just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `checked` attribute to the input.

```
<div class="btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons" id="rop1-1-cons">
<label class="btn btn-outline-primary active">
     <input type="radio" name="rop1-1-cons" id="rop1-1-cons-5" value="5" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">I
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I don't know how I missed it.